# Identifying changed rows in an Interbase table from a Delphi app

Tags: delphi, interbase

I know I can use a TIBEvents object in an application to receive events posted
by an Interbase server using POST_EVENT.

By setting up triggers on the IB database, I can use this mechanism to get notifications
**when** rows are updated, inserted or deleted, but not which rows are involved.  What prevents this from identifying the rows is the fact that the event name needs
to be known in advance by the IBEvents object. Is there a simple way to do this identification despite this limitation of the IBEvents object (or, more likely, of the POST_EVENT mechanism)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I've been looking into this very topic recently, and today I stumbled upon
a native Interbase solution, using a relatively new feature known as `Change Views` (see Stephen
Ball's blog for an introduction at https://delphiaball.co.uk/2015/02/06/interbase-change-views-part-1/.

Essentially, this involves setting up on the server a "subscription" which defines which tables
and kinds of operation are of interest (updates inserts and deletes), granting users the right to subscribe to the
subscription, and then setting up a client application to utilize the information
from the subscription.

A nice thing about `Change Views` is that they can be used with traditional IBX
components with only a few lines of code - see example below.  I haven't tried, but can't see any
reason why they couldn't be used with DBExpress or FireDAC as long as they support
setting the transaction type to "Snapshot".

A couple of wrinkles:

- Unless you rollback the transaction which retrieves the changes (as per the code
  below), the next time you view the subscription, you won't see the changes you saw
  last time.  If you want to see only subsequent changes next time, you call Commit instead of Rollback on the Select query.
- The subscription implementation hides changes to the table(s) made under your
  own log-in ID, so for set-up and testing, you need to use different logins, one
  to make the changes and the other to view them.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.OpenQuery;
var
  Sql : String;
begin
  //  Note that it is VITAL for the SELECT to return the desired results
  //  that the transaction type is set to "Snapshot", which can be done in the IDE
  //  using the Transaction Editor or in code as follows

  IBTransaction1.Params.Clear;
  IBTransaction1.Params.Add('concurrency');
  IBTransaction1.Params.Add('nowait');

  //  Next, activate the subscription
  Sql := 'SET SUBSCRIPTION "TABLE1CHANGES" ACTIVE;';
  IBQuery1.SQL.Text := Sql;
  IBQuery1.ExecSQL;

  //  Now we can retrieve the changed rows.  Note the "where" clause
  Sql := 'SELECT id, aname, avalue FROM table1 where aname is changed';  // or "is updated", 
  //  inserted, or deleted
  IBQuery1.SQL.Text := Sql;
  IBQuery1.Open;

end;
```

As ever with dynamic Sql in <strike>Delphi apps</strike> any application, beware of SQL injection.

**Update:**  Apparently the Interbase Express (IBX) component library has been updated to support subscriptions, I assume in Seattle (which I have but don't use).

Comment: Actually this code will not attackable by [SQLInjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (unless you modify it to build the SQL statement dynamically for user input)

Comment: @mjn:  Sure, I included it mainly because I noticed that Delphi-tagged questions tend to attract "tut-tut" comments when they include client-side Sql, sometimes regardless of whether the context makes this relevant or not.